# Fazer com que getopt ignore primeiro argumento

Tags: php, php-cli

Estou criando um PHP CLI, e queria rodar mais ou menos assim

```
php console.php comando -a foo -b bar -d
```

Porém com a função [`getopt`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getopt.php) não consigo passar o `comando` se não a função buga e não recebo nenhum dos outros argumentos. Preciso setar um parâmetro padrão como `-c`:

```
php console.php -c comando -a foo -b bar -d
```

Alguém sabe algum método para "parsear" os argumentos ignorando o primeiro?

PS: Também preciso pegar o primeiro argumento, pra saber qual comando deve ser executado.

[**Código: <sup>(github link)</sup>**](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/CMP/blob/356d19c7a1e8ee673baa59f126c467583f13fa56/CMP/Console.php#L37)

```
public function run() {

  $command = $this->getCommand();

  if (is_null($command)) return FALSE;
  $optcll = $command->getOptionCollection();
  $opts = $optcll->dump();

  // LINHA QUE PEGO OS ARGUMENTOS DO COMANDO
  $args = getopt($opts['options'], $opts['longopts']);

  return $command->execute($this, $args);

}
```

Comment: Qual é o código e `console.php`?

Comment: Aquilo ali é só exemplo, é a instanciação de uma classe que executa o código de outras classes e etc... O problema é a função `getopt` que estou usando pra pegar os parâmetros passados. https://github.com/KaduAmaral/CMP/blob/master/CMP/Console.php#L37

Comment: O código está público no repositório: https://github.com/KaduAmaral/CMP

Comment: A solução precisa ser necessariamente utilizando `getopt`?

Comment: Veja se neste post algo é aproveitável: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536611/1377664

Comment: Não muito, preciso de um _workaround_ pro PHP. Sei que o console do Symfony faz algo parecido com o que quero... Mas valeu pelo link @Dvdsamm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se satisfaz suas necessidades, mas existe a biblioteca [`docopt`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.php) para PHP.

Com ela, basta você escrever a documentação dos seus comandos que a biblioteca se encarrega de tratar as entradas, entregando a você um objeto com as informações fornecidas pelo usuário. Por exemplo, considerando o seu exemplo, poderíamos fazer:

```
<?php

$doc = <<<DOC
Descrição da aplicação.

Usage:
  console.php comando [-a A] [-b B] [-d]
  console.php (-h | --help)
  console.php --version

Options:
  -h --help     Exibe a mensagem de ajuda.
  --version     Exibe a versão.
  -a A          Valor de A.
  -b B          Valor de B.
  -d            Define como D.
DOC;

require('vendor/autoload.php');

$args = Docopt::handle($doc, array('version'=>'0.1.0'));

foreach ($args as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k.': '.json_encode($v).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Assim, pode-se exibir a mensagem de ajuda com o comando:

```
$ php console.php -h

Descrição da aplicação.

Usage:
  console.php comando [-a A] [-b B] [-d]
  console.php (-h | --help)
  console.php --version

Options:
  -h --help     Exibe a mensagem de ajuda.
  --version     Exibe a versão.
  -a A          Valor de A.
  -b B          Valor de B.
  -d            Define como D.
```

Exibir a versão com o comando:

```
$ php console.php --version

0.1.0
```

Ou executar os comandos previstos em *Usage*:

```
$ php console.php comando

comando: true
-a: null
-b: null
-d: false
--help: false
--version: false
```

Como defini as opções como opcionais e não os informei, ficaram definidos como `null` aqueles que possuem valor, como `-a` e `-b`, e como `false` os que são *flags*, como `-d`. Ao informar os valores, fica:

```
$ php console.php comando -a foo -b bar -d

comando: true
-a: "foo"
-b: "bar"
-d: true
--help: false
--version: false
```

Comment: Ainda estou estudando como se usa a função `getopt` para dizer se é possível fazer da maneira que tentou e como fazer. Atualizo a resposta assim que for possível.

Comment: Show de bola, pelo visto vai me atender perfeitamente, precisarei fazer alguns ajustes no código, mas assim que testar aviso...

Comment: Implementei aqui, ficou perfeito, valeu!